# Problem with the one page checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout

i have a problem with the validation in my website http://makemydrink.com/ for onepage checkout. in the front page when user click on ckeckout at the bottom line, they will get an error saying "Minimum purchase must be 500" and once they enter the next  onepage checkout page.Here at the bottom they can change their selection and if they click on the place order.. The value in checkout bottom field and review your order field doesn't match... so can anybody help me how to refresh the review your order div when customer remove their selection in checkout at bottom link in onepagecheckout page this page.

this is my review.phtml code.

```
<div id="checkout-review" class="onepagecheckout_block" >
<div class="op_block_title"><?php echo $this->__('Review Your Order') ?></div>
    <div id="checkout-review-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info') ?>
    </div>

    <div id="checkout-review-submit">    
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('agreements') ?>
        <div class="buttons-set" id="review-buttons-container">
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="fnGoToCheckout1(url);checkout.save(); return false;" id="God"><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></button>
            <span class="please-wait" id="review-please-wait" style="display:none;">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Submitting order information...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submitting order information...') ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Submitting order information...') ?>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not getting the solution please.

---

i can remove the cache in my browser but customers can't do. i want to refresh the review your order div each time when i delete an order from checkout in bottom link.i.e, when customer delete an one product, it'll show an alert "are you sure u want to remove? on pressing ok or cancel i want to refresh the review your order div in review.phtml page..

Please help me.

Comment: Just remove your cache in my browser it's working fine

Comment: Try to resolve javaScript errors showing in console.